# deploy to production with django gunicorn nginx, media files not showing

Tags: django, nginx, deployment, gunicorn

estoy tratando de que mi proyecto subido a un vps en Hostinger me muestre las imágenes que tengo alojadas en mi carpeta media. E tocado el archivo de configuración de nginx mil veces, para que me sirva los archivos media, pero no me los levanta. Sin embargo a los estáticos me los reconoce sin ningún problema, tanto mis estilos, como los del admin de django. Talvez sea algo que no estoy viendo. Les dejo mis archivos para que los revisen. Gracias!

SOLUCIONADO: Tenía todo bien, lo unico que tuve que hacer es crearme otro usuario en linux, ya que con el usuario root, que es el que estaba usando, no tenia permisos para acceder a la ruta. Espero a alguien le sirva.

*django 3.1, python3*

Mi carpeta raiz se ve así:

```
my_project/
 -app1/
 -app2/
 -statics/
 -media/
 -etc...
```

Asi esta configurado el settings.py:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/statics/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [ os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "statics")]
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Este es mi archivo de configuracion de nginx:

```
 upstream my_project {
        server my-ip:8000 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        client_max_body_size 4G;
        server_name my-ip;
        keepalive_timeout 5;

        location /my_project/static/ {
        alias /root/my_project/staticfiles/;
        }

        location /my_project/media/ {
        alias /root/my_project/media/;
        }

        location / {
        try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
        }

        location @proxy_to_app {
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_pass http://my_project;
        }
}
```